# Sorting list of names from external text file into common names (M, F and ALL) - Python 3

Tags: python

This is my first ever post because I can't seem to find a solution to my problem. I have a text file that contains a simple line by line list of different names distinguished from male and female by an M or F next to it. A simple example of this is:

```
John   M

John   M

Jim    M

Jim    M

Jim    M

Jim    M

Sally  F

Sally  F
```

You'll notice that names repeat because I want the python code to count what names occur the most and provide lists of most common names, male name and female names. I am very new to python and my understanding of many elements are limited at best.

Comment: There's a [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class in the stdlib that sounds ideal for your problem

Comment: Python's amazing. `Counter(line.strip() for line in open(file) if line != '\n')` – @Rotten194's answer is better, but I love how easy it is to craft quick things like that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply trying to group names into M and F categories?

If you only have two categories you could simply manually group them:

```
>>> >>> people = [('Mark', 'M'), ('Susan', 'F'), ('Mary', 'F'), ('Jake', 'M')]
>>> M_names = [ name for name, gender in people if gender == 'M' ]
>>> F_names = [ name for name, gender in people if gender == 'F' ]
>>> M_names, F_names
(['Mark', 'Jake'], ['Susan', 'Mary'])
```

However as you get more categories (undeclared gender, people who aren't exactly male/female, or grouping on something other than gender), `itertools` can give you a nicer solution:

```
>>> people = [('Mark', 'M'), ('Susan', 'F'), ('Mary', 'F'), ('Jake', 'M'), ('Morgan', 'Undeclared')]
>>> dict((k, list(name for name, _ in g)) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(people, key=lambda p: p[1]), key=lambda p: p[1]))
{'Undeclared': ['Morgan'], 'M': ['Mark', 'Jake'], 'F': ['Susan', 'Mary']}
```

That's a pretty complicated one-liner, but conceptually it's simple. First we have to sort the data by key, this is because `groupby` will sort in the order the data appears, and will create separate groups if there are non-continuous groups in the data. We then pass that sorted data to `groupby`, which returns an iterator that yields tuples of a type and another iterator of data elements that have that type. We pass that to `dict` to create a dictionary of type -> list of names with that type (stripping off the second type element of each tuple  to avoid redundancy).

You could also write that line as:

```
>>> genders_to_names = {}
>>> sorted_by_gender = sorted(people, key=lambda p: p[1]) # [('Susan', 'F'), ('Mary', 'F'), ('Mark', 'M'), ('Jake', 'M'), ('Morgan', 'Undeclared')]
>>> for gender, names in itertools.groupby(sorted_by_gender, key=lambda p: p[1]):
...     genders_to_names[gender] = list(name for name, _ in names)
>>> print(genders_to_names)
{'Undeclared': ['Morgan'], 'M': ['Mark', 'Jake'], 'F': ['Susan', 'Mary']} # same as before
```

But who wants to do that ;)

Counting is very easy! Just import `collections` and use `Counter`:

```
>>> collections.Counter(['Mark', 'Mark', 'Joe', 'John'])
Counter({'Mark': 2, 'John': 1, 'Joe': 1})
>>> collections.Counter(['Mark', 'Mark', 'Joe', 'John'])['Mark']
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete program that reads a named file and prints the five most common names in each gender.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import collections

with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
  lines = [line.split() for line in file]
males = collections.Counter(name for (name, gender) in lines if gender == 'M')
femes = collections.Counter(name for (name, gender) in lines if gender == 'F')

print males.most_common(5)
print femes.most_common(5)
```